# How to properly simplify and trig substitute this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

$\int\frac{{\sqrt {25-x^2}}}x\,dx$

I see that it is the form $a-x^2$.

Let $x = 5\sin\theta$

Then substitute this $x$ value in and 
get $\int\frac {\sqrt {25-(5 \sin\theta)^2}}{5 \sin\theta}\, d\theta $

Take the root, simplified to $\int\frac { {5-(5 \sin\theta)}}{5 \sin\theta}\,d\theta $

Factor out 5 and cancel, simplified to $\int\frac { {5(1-( \sin\theta))}}{5 (\sin\theta)}\, d\theta $

Divide by $\sin\theta$ to get $\int\frac { (1-( \sin\theta))}{ (\sin\theta)}\, d\theta $

Simplified to $\int\frac {1}{ \sin\theta}d\,\theta - 1 $

I am stuck here and I can't figure it out. Supposedly the answer simplifies to  $\int-5 \sin x \tan x \,dx$

Comment: $\sqrt{a^2-x^2} $ does not imply $a-x$.  Also where is dx ?

Comment: $\sqrt{25-(5 \sin\theta)^2} \ne 5-(5 \sin\theta)$ but $\sqrt{25-(5 \sin\theta)^2} = 5 |\cos\theta)|.$

Comment: You simplify WHAT?? Look.

$$\sqrt{25 - 25\sin^2\theta} = \sqrt{25(1 - \sin^2\theta)} = 5\cos\theta$$

Also the $\text{d}x \to \text{d}\theta$ is missing.

Comment: Whoops thank you - I added the dx.
@HenryTuring Oh dang, I messed up bad. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently this ends up giving you a hyperbolic tangent for the antiderivative, so it seems a little more difficult than that.

Comment: @KentW, See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/949882/evaluate-int-fracx3-sqrt81x2-16dx-using-trigonometric-substitution/949886#949886

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your steps, with corrections:

$\int\frac{{\sqrt {25-x^2}}}x\,dx$

I see that it is the form $a-x^2$.

Let $x = 5\sin\theta$
Then $dx=5\cos\theta d\theta$

Then substitute this $x$ and $dx$ value in and 
get $\int\frac {\sqrt {25-(5 \sin\theta)^2}}{5 \sin\theta}\, 5\cos\theta d\theta $

Using the trig identity, simplify the root to get  $\int\frac {\sqrt {25\cos^2\theta}}{5 \sin\theta}\, 5\cos\theta d\theta $

Factor out 5 and cancel, simplified to get  $\int\frac {5|cos\theta|}{ \sin\theta}\, \cos\theta d\theta $

(Note that we're taking the square root of a square here, so we should get the absolute value. Unless you're on a domain where cosine is positive, you can't neglect this.)

This seems to not be where you want to go.

Let's try instead a substitution of $x=5\cos\theta$. Then $dx=-5\sin\theta d\theta$

Thus, we have $-\int\frac{\sqrt{25-(5\cos\theta)^2}}{5\cos\theta}5\sin\theta d\theta$

After simplification, we get $-5\int\frac{|\sin\theta|}{\cos\theta}\sin\theta d\theta$

The simplification you get works if x is such that $\sin\theta$ is always positive, so we can drop the absolute value sign.

Answer (score 4):

If $x = 5\sin\theta$ then $dx = 5\cos\theta\, d\theta.$ That was neglected.

You also replaced $\sqrt{25 - (5\sin\theta)^2}$ with $5 - 5\sin\theta.$ That is also not correct. Notice that, for example,
$$
\sqrt{5^2 - 3^3} = \sqrt{25-9} = \sqrt{16} = 4 \ne 5-3, \text{ so } \sqrt{5^2-3^2} \text{ differs from } 5-3.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let us begin by $x=5t $ and $dx=5\,dt $.

it becomes

$$\int\frac {\sqrt {25 (1-t^2)}}{5t}5\,dt $$

$$=5\int \frac {\sqrt {1-t^2}}{t}\,dt $$
now put $t=\sin (u) $ and $dt=\cos (u)\,du $.

we get

$$\pm 5\int \frac {\cos(u)}{\sin (u)}\cos (u)\,du $$

$$=\pm 5 \int \frac {\cos^2 (u)}{1-\cos^2 (u)}\sin (u)\,du $$

put $v=\cos (u) $ and you can finish.

Comment: how did you get the last step? Specifically the denominator. From sin(u) to $(1-cos^2(u))$?

Comment: @KentW sin^2=1-cos^2

Comment: But we have sin(u) and du= dt/cos(u). I don't know how you arrived at sin^2 to get to the last step, or the sin(u) outside of the fraction.

Comment: He multiplied top and bottom by $\sin(u)$ to get a $\sin^2$ on bottom, and then did the substitution.

Comment: @JKreft Yes thx.