# Approach to evaluate the integral $\int \frac{1}{{x^3}\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}dx$ using basic substitution.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

So I was attempting a basic indefinite integral problem which goes like $$\int \frac{1}{{x^3}\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}dx$$ for which I used the substitution $x=a\sec\theta$ which on differentiating gave $$dx=a\sec\theta\tan\theta d\theta$$. Now after further substitution and evaluation, I get the following steps-

$$I=\int\frac{a\sec\theta\tan\theta d\theta}{{a^3\sec^3\theta}{\sqrt{a^2(\sec^2\theta-1)}}}$$

Now using $$\sec^2\theta-1=\tan^2\theta$$ and further cancelling the terms,

$$I=\int\frac{\cos^2\theta d\theta}{a^3}$$

which on integrating using $$\cos^2\theta= \frac{1+\cos2\theta}{2}$$ and substituting back $$\theta=\sec^{-1}\frac{x}{a}$$ , the final answer looks something like

$$I=\frac{\sec^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\sin\left(2\sec^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)\right)}{4a^3} + c $$

But I saw some solutions on internet and none of them matches with my solution. So I want to know where have I went wrong using this approach. Also I skipped some intermediate steps here in this question so please rectify me at what step I went wrong and suggest the correct substitution.

P.S. I am new to LaTeX so I tried my best to format but there might be errors so please edit if required.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/949882/evaluate-int-fracx3-sqrt81x2-16dx-using-trigonometric-substitution

Comment: @labbhattacharjee in that question the x^3 term is in numerator but here since it is in denominator, how would this approach work? Also what is wrong in my trigonometric substitution?

Comment: @Aayush Start by substituting $x=\frac{1}{u}$. Now the power term is in the numerator. Can you take it from there?

Comment: @DavidH I understood this now. But can you please also elaborate on where my original method went wrong?

Comment: @Aayush Your final answer is actually only off by a factor of $2$. The integral should be $\frac{\sec^{-1}\frac{x}{a}+\frac{1}{2}\sin(2sec^{-1}\frac{x}{a})}{\color{red}{2}a^3}+C$. I'm guessing you made a mistake computing the antiderivative of $\frac{1+\cos2\theta}{2}$ and somehow wound up with an extra factor of $\frac12$.

Comment: @Aayush, Nothing wrong in using trigonometric substitution. I think it is easier to apply $$u=\sqrt{x^2-a^2}$$  It will work as long as the exponent is odd  be it $-3$ or $+3$

Comment: Well it might be different by a constant for instance $\int2\sin x\cos x dx = \sin^2 x + C\quad \text{or} \quad-\cos^2 x +C $ depending on which u pick as the substitution

Comment: Perhaps use some trig identity to simplfy ... $$\sin(2\operatorname{arcsec}(x/a)) = \frac{2a\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}{x^2}$$